# Somando valores contidos em um arquivo em C

Tags: c, array, algoritmo, lógica, soma

Preciso escrever um algoritmo em linguagem C em que o usuário entrará com um valor x. Caso o valor x não conste dentro do arquivo (matriz) que serve como base de dados, o valor imediatamente acima e abaixo do informado devem ser somados.

Por exemplo, o usuário digita o valor 0.793, no entanto, no banco de dados só há os valores 0.75 e 0.81. Como comparar o valor digitado com os contidos no arquivo e pegar esses dois últimos valores mais próximos do valor informado pelo usuário, utilizando uma estrutura de repetição e somar? Alguém tem ideia de por onde começar o raciocínio? Segue como os valores estão dispostos no arquivo e uma parte do algoritmo.

```
0.6   883.0
0.75  211.8
0.81  912.8
0.86  110.4
0.9   622.1
```

```
printf("Digite um valor qualquer: ");
    scanf("%f", &val);
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < lin; i++){
            for(j = 0; j < col; j++)
                fscanf(lerArquivo, "%f", &matriz[i][j]);
            for(j = 0; j < col; j++)
             if (val == matriz[i][0])
                printf("%0.2f\t", matriz[i][j]);
              }
```

Comment: poste algo minimamente compilável. Não escreva um programa interativo se puder evitar. Pra que vai digitar um valor qualquer toda vez que for testar isso? Só vai perder tempo. Quanto à lógica use 2 valores, o menor maior e o maior menor valor, e mantenha atualizado até encontrar o valor exato no arquivo ou terminar o arquivo e aí mostre as parcelas e a soma

Comment: @arfneto não há como evitar ser interativo. Trata-se de uma aplicação que depende de um valor requerido do usuário e se o valor não estiver contido será necessário obter uma média entre os valores mais próximos. Quanto a parte lógica, seria possível escrever a forma como você pensou? Se não, agradeço pela resposta.

Comment: É claro que há, Paloma. Apenas no seu exemplo escreva `val=0.793` e rode o programa até obter a resposta esperada. Depois teste com `622.1` a ver se dá certo para o último valor... Depois que estiver funcionando você põe a irrelevante leitura do valor. Ou como eu disse vai perder tempo a toa a toda vez que for testar isso...

Answer (score 0):

Como eu comentei, basta ler os valores do arquivo e manter controle do menor maior e do maior menor que o valor alvo, por mais que seja esquisito de ler esse parágrafo :)

Como eu disse num comentário, também não há razão para escrever um programa interativo: toda vez que for testar vai ficar digitando valores e perdendo tempo. Conclua o programa e depois coloque uma instrução pra ler o valor. Só depois.

E tem uma pegadinha importante: pode ser que o valor procurado seja menor que todos no arquivo ou pelo contrário, seja maior que todos no arquivo. Deve prever essa condição.

De todo modo é um simples `if`.

Vou deixar um exemplo a seguir.

#### Escreva em torno dos dados

No geral precisa varrer o arquivo de entrada e ler todos os números. Então é a maneira trivial de começar o programa.

#### O arquivo de teste `entrada.txt`

É o mesmo arquivo que postou

```
0.6   883.0
0.75  211.8
0.81  912.8
0.86  110.4
0.9   622.1
```

#### lendo os dados: `f0.c`

Esse programa lê todos os valores e mostra na tela um por linha

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int         res     = 0;
    double      value   = 0;
    const char* arquivo = "entrada.txt";
    FILE*       fp      = fopen(arquivo, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) return -1; // nao abriu
    while ( 1 == (res = fscanf(fp, "%lg", &value) ) )
        printf("    %10.2f\n", value);
    fclose( fp);
    return 0;
}
```

E mostra

```
PS C:\SOPT> ./f0
          0.60
        883.00
          0.75
        211.80
          0.81
        912.80
          0.86
        110.40
          0.90
        622.10
```

E assim é um bom começo...

#### implementando a lógica dentro do loop

```
    // controle dos valores 
    double delta       = 0.00001;  // tolerancia

    char   nenhum_maior = 1;
    double maior       = 0;

    char   nenhum_menor = 1;
    double menor       = 0;
```

É melhor usar uma tolerância nas comparações porque são valores de ponto flutuante e usar `==` sempre traz surpresas. Se o cara digitar `622.100001` e lá no arquivo tem `622.1` será que vai dar igual?

Essa é a razão da variável `delta`. qualquer diferença menor que `delta` e o alvo será considerado encontrado.

`maior` e `menor` salvam os valores mais próximos encontrados. E os dois `char` servem para não ter que ficar pensando nisso: `nenhum_menor` vale `1` quer dizer que ainda não apareceu nenhum valor menor que o alvo.

Como não queremos um programa interativo: o valor vale por padrão `0.793`, o valor que sugeriu. E se vier um valor na linha de comando esse será o alvo.

Simples assim.

Então um `if` dentro do `while` do programa acima deve resolver a busca. E ao sair do loop basta mostrar os resultados.

#### Exemplos de saída `f1` é o nome do programa

```
C:\SOPT>

C:\SOPT> ./f1
Valor alvo:           0.79300000
O maior valor mais proximo de           0.79300000 presente no arquivo =           0.81000000
O menor valor mais proximo de           0.79300000 presente no arquivo =           0.75000000

C:\SOPT> ./f1 -1000
Valor alvo:       -1000.00000000
O maior valor mais proximo de       -1000.00000000 presente no arquivo =           0.60000000
todos valores maiores que o procurado

C:\SOPT> ./f1 2000.
Valor alvo:        2000.00000000
todos valores menores que o procurado
O menor valor mais proximo de        2000.00000000 presente no arquivo =         912.80000000

C:\SOPT> ./f1 0.8600002
Valor alvo:           0.86000020
Alvo:           0.86000020 Lido:           0.86000000. Considerado igual
C:\SOPT>
```

#### O programa `f1.c`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int         res     = 0;
    double      valor   = 0;
    const char* arquivo = "entrada.txt";
    FILE*       fp      = fopen(arquivo, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) return -1; // nao abriu

    // nunca escreva um programa interativo
    double alvo = 0.793; // vai procurar por esse
    if (argc > 1) alvo = atof(argv[1]);
    printf("Valor alvo: %20.8f\n", alvo);
    
    // controle dos valores 
    double delta       = 0.00001;  // tolerancia

    char   nenhum_maior = 1;
    double maior       = 0;

    char   nenhum_menor = 1;
    double menor       = 0;

    while (1 == (res = fscanf(fp, "%lg", &valor)))
    {
        //printf("[%10.2f]\n", valor);
        if (alvo >= valor)
        {   // valor do arquivo menor que o procurado
            if ((alvo - valor) < delta)
            {  // ok: considera igual entao
                printf(
                    "Alvo: %20.8f Lido: %20.8f. "
                    "Considerado igual\n",
                    alvo, valor);
                return 0;
            }
            // ok: diferente entao, e menor
            if (nenhum_menor)
            {
                nenhum_menor = 0;      // o primeiro
                menor        = valor;  // salva
                continue;
            }
            if (valor > menor) menor = valor;
        }
        else
        {  // alvo menor que valor lido do arquivo
            if ((valor - alvo) < delta)
            {  // ok: considera igual entao
                printf(
                    "Alvo: %20.8f Lido: %20.8f. "
                    "Considerado igual\n",
                    alvo, valor);
                return 0;
            }
            // ok: diferente entao, e menor
            if (nenhum_maior)
            {
                nenhum_maior = 0;      // o primeiro
                maior        = valor;  // salva
                continue;
            }
            if (valor < maior) maior = valor;
        }
    };  // while
    if (nenhum_maior)
        printf("todos valores menores que o procurado\n");
    else
        printf(
            "O maior valor mais proximo de %20.8f presente no "
            "arquivo = %20.8f\n", alvo,
            maior);

    if (nenhum_menor)
        printf("todos valores maiores que o procurado\n");
    else
        printf(
            "O menor valor mais proximo de %20.8f presente no "
            "arquivo = %20.8f\n",  alvo, 
            menor);
    fclose( fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: :) E dessa vez levou mais de 1 hora para uma resposta minha ser marcada como inútil! Mas é bom pra eu lembrar que preciso melhorar.